# How to make a RequiredAttribute for create not for edit of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a model containing a property of HttpPostedFileBase type, and I have created a custom validation attribute which implements RequiredAttribute to make some validations. It works perfectly when you create the model. However I don't want to make any validation when you edit the model (optional HttpPostedFileBase property when you edit the model). How do I make it?

Answer (score 3):

Your attribute is simple metadata added to a property of a class. This attribute has no information about what you do with the class, i.e. if you're using this class to edit or to create a new entity.

So, the answer is that you cannot do that directly in the attribute. So the only solution is to "bypass" the attribute where you're using it, if you're editing the value. There are several alternatives:

1. use two different models, one for editing, the other for creating. And decorate the property only in the model for creating
2. remove the validation, or the error, using some code to do it: for example, you can remove the property error from the `ModelState` in a post action for the Edit action.

Obviously the easiest is 1. You can use a base class with all the fields, but those which have different treatement, and then inherit it for creation or edition. It's not strange to represent the same data with different models when you use MVC: a model for viewing, a model for showing the editor, a model for receiving the result of an edition... so, using several different models is not a problem at all. You can use `AutoMapper` or `ValueInjecter` to simplify moving data between entities and models.

Comment: I have marked property with NotMapped so that it will not be saved in database but still when the property is empty it throws exception. Is just because it is marked with my validation attribute (required)?

Comment: When is the exception thrown? Is there any inner exception or additional info? The data annotations are used by several different layers, for example by EF and MVC binding.